Get axes mosaic label after passed into function?
I want the mosaic layout label of an axes after axes has been passed into a function.
Simplified example:
def test_function(ax):
    print(ax)

mosaic_subplot_layout = {'axes': [['boxplot'], ['histogram'], ['histogram'], ['histogram']]}
my_figure = plt.figure()
ax_dict = my_figure.subplot_mosaic(mosaic_subplot_layout['axes'])
for axes in ax_dict:
    test_function(ax=ax_dict[axes])

Returns:
Axes(0.125,0.712609;0.775x0.167391)
Axes(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.56913)

Desired:
boxplot
histogram

Googling this all I've found are tips on how to change tick labels or other labels, not helpful. The way I've found to do this is like so:
def test_function(ax):
    print(ax)
mosaic_subplot_layout = {'axes': [['boxplot'], ['histogram'], ['histogram'], ['histogram']]}
my_figure = plt.figure()
ax_dict = my_figure.subplot_mosaic(mosaic_subplot_layout['axes'])
for axes in ax_dict:
    test_function(ax=axes)

But this creates other problems in my real code and isn't desirable.
What should I try next?

ax_dict, by definition, has to contain references to the Axes instances created by subplot_mosaic. You want a way to find the names of those in the mosaic, and you already have it (axes, rather than ax_dict[axes]). Without more details about how this causes other problems, I think you'll need to be more specific about what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Each artist can have a label and the mosaic labels are used as Axes labels when internally adding the subplots. So it's simply
def test_function(ax):
    print(ax.get_label())

Example (your example mosaic has only 2 Axes due to repeating dict keys):
mosaic_subplot_layout = {'axes': [['boxplot'], ['histogram'], ['barplot'], ['image']]}
my_figure = plt.figure()
ax_dict = my_figure.subplot_mosaic(mosaic_subplot_layout['axes'])
for axes in ax_dict:
    test_function(ax=ax_dict[axes])

Output:
boxplot
histogram
barplot
image

